# Volatile local variable in LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized?

Tags: c#, volatile

I was looking at `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref T, Func{T})` in Reflector, and there appears to be a volatile local variable in that method `volatile object local1 = s_barrier;`
.  I can think of two possible reasons for this:

1. .NET may get to use features that are not supported by a given language, or
2. The actual code does not declare a volatile local variable, but when the compiled code is decompiled by Reflector, it looks like a volatile local variable.

Does anyone know which is the case here (or whether there might be some other explanation)? If it is a matter of decompilation, does anyone have an idea of what the "true" code would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a Reflector bug : it's just a normal volatile *read* of the `s_barrier` field. There's no "special" IL here that's not expressible in C#.

```
 L_000d: volatile. 
 L_000f: ldsfld object modreq(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile) System.Threading.LazyInitializer::s_barrier
```

This is just the normal code the compiler emits when reading from a static volatile field.

---

Here's a simpler repro:  just compile the following (wrapped in a type) in *release* mode:

```
private static volatile object field;

private static void Main()
{
    var temp = field;
}
```

Reflector produces the following decompiled C#:

```
private static void Main()
{
    volatile object field = Program.field;
}
```

when the IL is actually:

```
L_0000: volatile. 
L_0002: ldsfld object modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile) WindowsFormsApplication1.Program::field
L_0007: pop 
L_0008: ret
```

**UPDATE**: 
Here's my guess about what's happening:  In release mode, the C# compiler optimizes away the assignment of the value of the field (the result of the volatile read) to the local variable (the `stloc` instruction) since the local is not subsequently used. This appears to confuse Reflector. If you changed the method to use the subsequently use local, the `stloc` (or similar) instruction would indeed be emitted, following which the decompiled output from Reflector looks sensible.

Comment: Agreed.  Specific to a release build, somehow.

Comment: I came across the same line of Code. Could you maybe explain why this is implemented this way? Because I don't get it why there is a need of this line

Answer (score 2):

Ani is right.  This is the actual source code, as retrieved from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).  Reflector is nice but can't hold a candle to actual commented source code.

```
    public static T EnsureInitialized<T>(ref T target) where T : class
    {
        // Fast path.
        if (target != null)
        {
            object barrierGarbage = s_barrier; // Insert a volatile load barrier. Needed on IA64.

            return target;
        }

        return EnsureInitializedCore<T>(ref target, LazyHelpers<T>.s_activatorFactorySelector);
    }
```

The naming choice gives some insight too in what the Microsoft programmer thought about the joy of writing code for the Titanium.

Comment: @Hans, thank you too. I managed to go all this time without knowing that the actual commented source code was available.

Comment: That would maybe be the Itanium? ;)