# C# Lazy Initialization && Race-to-initialize?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

After [reading](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=t1de8nSVYnkC&pg=PA906&lpg=PA906&dq=%22LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized%20%28ref%20_expensive,%22&source=bl&ots=24qfWwIk7y&sig=9ygi5-TUZEWf1LD0-KKPUbVVrQo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XLUHUMDuCeLP0QXRppHvBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized%20%28ref%20_expensive,%22&f=false) about `LazyInitializer`  that it's :

> It offers another mode of initialization that has multiple threads
>   race to initialize.

here is a sample :

```
Expensive _expensive;
public Expensive Expensive
     {
       get // Implement double-checked locking
         {
           LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized (ref _expensive,() => new Expensive());
           return _expensive;
         }
     }
```

**Question #1**

looking at : 
[image]

why #A says its implements double-checking locking ? it is just a get proeprty ?

**Question #2**

Does #B (lambda expression) is thread safe ?

**Question #3**

So i searched about this *"race-to-initialize"* thing by looking at  a sample:

```
volatile Expensive _expensive;
public Expensive Expensive
{
  get
  {
    if (_expensive == null)
    {
      var instance = new Expensive();
      Interlocked.CompareExchange (ref _expensive, instance, null);
    }
    return _expensive;
  }
}
```

and then i thought  about : isnt race to initialize is thread safe ?

e/g/ if 2 threads get into  :

[image]

the expensive object will be created twice !

So again  , 3 question

1)why #A says its implements double-checking locking ? it is just a get proeprty ?

2)Does #B (lambda expression) is thread safe ?

3)isnt race to initialize is thread safe

Comment: the comment "// Implement ..." sounds more like a plan for the future, i'd say

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various overloads of `EnsureInitialized`. Some accepts a `synclock` object (that can be `null` and will be created by the `EnsureInitialized` method). Others don't have a `synclock` as a parameter. All the `EnsureInitialized` guarantee that if called at the same time by two (or more) different threads while the object is uninitialized, the two threads will receive back a reference to the same object. So:

```
Expensive _expensive;

// On thread 1
LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized (ref _expensive,() => new Expensive());

// On thread 2
LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized (ref _expensive,() => new Expensive());
```

the `_expensive` object that will be seen by the two threads will be the same.

The only problem is that `new Expensive()` could be called twice (once per thread, so in a multi-thread race it could be called even more times.)

If you don't want it, use the `synclock` overload:

```
Expensive _expensive;
object _sync = null;
bool _useless;

// On thread 1
LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized (ref _expensive, ref useless, ref _sync, () => new Expensive());

// On thread 2
LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized (ref _expensive, ref useless, ref _sync, () => new Expensive());
```

Now the `new Expensive()` will be called only once, for every possible combination of the two (or more) threads running.

Comment: does _race-to-initialize_ is a _race condition_ ? ( is it the same term ?)

Comment: @RoyiNamir It depends if the initializer has a side effect :-) If it doesn't have a side effect then it isn't really a race, because (taken from the wiki) `A race condition or race hazard is a flaw in an electronic system or process whereby the output or result of the process is unexpectedly and critically dependent on the sequence or timing of other events.` No side effect => no difference in output (clearly a very high use of resources could be classified as a side effect). If the method is `new List<int>()` then there isn't any problem. if it's `transfer 100$ to someone` then there is.

Comment: so what benefit i have using `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized` ( without syncobj) ? I could have use `Lazy<Expensive> _expensive = new Lazy<Expensive>
(() => new Expensive(), true);` which also be Thread sagfe && lazy...

Comment: @RoyiNamir Benefit over what? Over using directly the `CompareExchange`? That you don't have to comprehend the magic behind it, and that you (or someone less verse in multithreading that works on the same code as you) can't break it. It is correctly-implemented pattern.

Comment: (maybe i didnt understand you) but please have alook at the code at Question #3. i wrote this code to understand what is race to initialize ( still dont understand). also it uses there : `Interlocked.CompareExchange` and not `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized` so ? can you please fix things up for me ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It should work as is. It seems equivalent to the code of `EnsureInitialized` (minus a `null` check for failure of the `Func<T>` that is useless because you are using a constructor). Probably the `volatile` is useless (but even the `LazyInitializer` introduces a read memory barrier when the value is != null, by reading a private volatile member, so perhaps it's better that you leave it)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Found why the LazyInitializer uses a private volatile field http://stackoverflow.com/a/8702644/613130 . There is a reason why it's better to use professionally implemented patterns :-)

Comment: , does `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized (ref _expensive,() => new Expensive());` is thread safe ? I dont think so because looking at http://i.stack.imgur.com/DQJJA.jpg shows that 2 race threads can call and initialize 2 Expensive objects. ( but does creating 2 objects means - it aint thread safe ?) 1 thing i understnad , the lock helps in case of race , and only 1 expensive will be created.I guess im having trouble connecting "thread safe" to double initialization. can you please explain ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir As I have written you can be thread safe and have multiple initializations. If `new Expensive()` is thread safe and side-effect free then even if it's initialized twice there isn't any problem. Otherwise you should use the overload with the sync object

Comment: What about Lazy<T> ? Does it offer a solution for  : race to initialize ? I dont want my Lazy<T> will be creating the `Expensive` object many times

Comment: isn't `object _sync = null;`  should be  `_sync = new Object()` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, it can be null. From MSDN: `A reference to an object used as the mutually exclusive lock for initializing target. If syncLock is null, a new object will be instantiated.`