# C# Lazy <T> & Race-to-initialize?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, lazy-evaluation

(*After asking [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555755/c-sharp-lazy-initialization-race-to-initialize)   , I still have a question.*)

The whole idea(AFAIK) with `Lazy<T>` , is to create the object *only* when we need it.
Why ? becuase it's expensive to create.

The *last* thing I would want is that the `Expensive` object will be created `>1` times.

I don't care if many threads will eventually yields the same reference. I just don't want them to create more than one instance.

so `Lazyinitializer` handle this by `syncLock`:

```
LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized (ref _expensive, ref useless, ref _sync, () => new Expensive());
```

But how does `Lazy<T>` can handle it ? 
I've searched in msdn and couldnt find any `syncLock` overload ...

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking how Lazy works internally? Lazy does guarantee that only one will ever be created, as per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx):

> By default, Lazy objects are thread-safe. That is, if the constructor
>   does not specify the kind of thread safety, the Lazy objects it
>   creates are thread-safe. In multi-threaded scenarios, the first thread
>   to access the Value property of a thread-safe Lazy object initializes
>   it for all subsequent accesses on all threads, and all threads share
>   the same data. Therefore, it does not matter which thread initializes
>   the object, and race conditions are benign.

If you are in fact asking how it works internally, it seems to be using a `lock` of some sort:

```
        object obj = Volatile.Read<object>(ref this.m_threadSafeObj);
        bool flag = false;
        try
        {
            if (obj != Lazy<T>.ALREADY_INVOKED_SENTINEL)
            {
                Monitor.Enter(obj, ref flag);
            }
            if (this.m_boxed == null)
            {
                boxed = this.CreateValue();
                this.m_boxed = boxed;
                Volatile.Write<object>(ref this.m_threadSafeObj, Lazy<T>.ALREADY_INVOKED_SENTINEL);
            }
            else
            {
                boxed = (this.m_boxed as Lazy<T>.Boxed);
                if (boxed == null)
                {
                    Lazy<T>.LazyInternalExceptionHolder lazyInternalExceptionHolder = this.m_boxed as Lazy<T>.LazyInternalExceptionHolder;
                    lazyInternalExceptionHolder.m_edi.Throw();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(obj);
            }
        }
```

Notice the Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit calls.

Comment: While it is using Monitor, it isn't doing so in what I would call a "simple" way.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to look at the constructor overloads which take a `LazyThreadSafetyMode`.

```
Lazy<T> lazy = new Lazy<T>(() => new T, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
```

`Lazy<T>` is basically a user-friendly version of `LazyInitializer`, with the exact implementation of single- or multi-threaded init being hidden behind that enum.

Comment: wt* ? was it so hard to add syncobj like they created in LazyInitializer?

Comment: `Lazy<T>` with `ExecutionAndPublication` is equivalent to `LazyInitializer` with `syncLock`. You will only ever get one instance.

Comment: @Royi often it isn't about whether something is "hard" (although that can be a factor) - it is: is it needed? is it useful? I'm guessing it failed one of those two. The monitor usage inside Lazy-of-T is quite subtle.

Comment: But according to @bfree - Lazy<T> do it automatically...?

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't understand ,  Cory says i must add `ExecutionAndPublication` in order to get the desire result. but Bfree says it is already there and using lock 
(and it will always create 1 instance)....so ?

Comment: Yes. It locks on the `Func<T>` delegate you pass in, then replaces it with a sentinal `Func<T>` that signals if it's been initialized. It is a clever, simple way to implement the single-instance behavior.

Comment: The default ctor specifies `ExecutionAndPublication`. Bfree is correct, you can just use the default ctor.